# Rename folder name recursively using java

Tags: java

Below is my folder structure, i want to rename all folder name from "abc" to "test"recursively.
And i want to change the file name "abcv1.txt" to "testV1.txt" recursively where V1 is constant .I tried renameTo() in my code but its not working for directory. I have not write the code to change the file name.Any suggestion will helpful

```
Folder1
  --abc
     --xyz
        --a.txt
Folder2
  --def
  --ghi
    --abc
      --abc
        --abcV1.txt


public static void RenameFiles (File dir){


            String regexe = "abc";
            String replacement = "test";

            // Allocate a Pattern object to compile a regexe
            Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regexe, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
            Matcher matcher;

             // directory to be processed
            int count = 0;

            File[] files = dir.listFiles();
            for (File file : files) {

                if (file.isDirectory()) {


                    File parentDir = file.getParentFile(); // to get the parent dir 
                    String parentDirName = file.getParentFile().getName(); // to get the parent dir name

                       // get filename, exclude path
                    matcher = pattern.matcher(parentDirName); // allocate Matches with input
                    if (matcher.find()) {
                       ++count;
                       String outFilename = matcher.replaceAll(replacement);
                       System.out.print(parentDirName + " -> " + outFilename);

                       if (file.renameTo(new File(dir.getParent()+ "\\" + outFilename))) {  // execute rename
                          System.out.println(" SUCCESS");
                       } else {
                          System.out.println(" FAIL");
                       }


                } else {
                    // System.out.println("file:" + file.getCanonicalPath() +"\n"
                    // System.out.println(file.getName()+"\n");

                //  String path = file.getCanonicalPath();
                    String filename = file.getName();


                }
                    RenameFiles(file);
            }


    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to check items before recursive enterance. 
And you can make some changes in this code to seperate and operate  'file and folder'.
Because you use 'if statement' when file is directory only. 
So it can be not working in file condition.

- write from mobile phone -